# I must have done something wrong installing sample database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I downloaded file SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe (version 10.00.1600.22), and used it to install SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services, which I think has capabilities comparable to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.  Upon install, all Prerequisite conditions were met, and installation was completed with no failures.

This version of SQL Server includes SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express.  The Management Studio doesn't show in Add or Remove Programs, and there's no icon for it on my desktop, but it does appear at Start | All Programs | Microsoft SQL Server 2008 | SQL Server Management Studio.

I then downloaded file SQL2008.AdventureWorks_All_Databases.x86.msi, and attempted to use it to install AdventureWorks Sample Databases for SQL Server 2008.

I got the following error:

"PrepInstance() failed for MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS.
The following features are missing: Full Text Search
Fix the problems and re-run setup."

When I ran the Management Studio, it said:

Server type: Database Engine
Server name: NULL\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: Windows Authentication

and gave me the following error:

"Could not connect to NULL\SQLEXPRESS. Server not found or not accessible."

I guess this must be because NULL is not a valid directory.

Now the Server name is just coming up blank.

Any help?

Comment: In SQL parlance "NULL\SQLEXPRESS" would refer to the SQL instance named "SQLEXPRESS" on host "NULL".

Comment: Any idea on how the host would be assigned a value of NULL?  Or how I would assign a value that would refer to the local computer on which the database was resident?